# CakePHP3 get user in default.ctp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I work on CakePHP 3 project. I want to display username of the logged user from **default.ctp** so I tried this:

```
//in default.ctp   
 $user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
    if(!empty($user)) {
        echo 'Hi ', $user['user_name'];
    }
```

It doesn't work and I found other solution which tells me to put the current user in session from **AppController** it doesn't work either.

```
// in AppController      
function beforeFilter(){
  $user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
  $this->set('username', $user['username']);
}
```

and in **default.ctp**:

```
<?=$username?>
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php   $session = $this->request->session(); // less than 3.5
        // $session = $this->request->getSession(); // 3.5 or more
        $user_data = $session->read('Auth.User');
        if(!empty($user_data)){
            print_r($user_data);
  }?>
```

try this hope it help's..

Comment: You shouldn't be retrieving the authorised user's data using the session like this. You should be using the Auth component like shown in burzum's answer. Avoid using the Session approach shown here!

Answer (score 8):

Accessing the session is *the wrong* approach to this. The auth system in CakePHP can handle different sources of the user and the session *won't* work for stateless auth systems for example.

So the proper approach is to get the user from the abstracted auth system and *not* reading it directly from the session. Also the session approach will screw up in the case the session key changes.

In the AppController just add this:

```
public function beforeRender() {
    $this->set('user', $this->Auth->user());
}
```

Then access the $user var in the view. [My plugin](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-user-tools) even contains [a helper](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-user-tools/blob/master/src/View/Helper/AuthHelper.php) to deal with common tasks of the user data in the view.

Comment: Thank you this helped me in my project not only to pass `$user`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to include --
`use Cake\View\Helper\SessionHelper ;` // in app controller

You have got right snippet of  code--

```
// in AppController  , this function being called before every request  
function beforeFilter(){
  $user = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
  $this->set('username', $user['username']);
}
```

and obviously these set values will available in your views layout files.

```
<?=$username?> or <?php echo $username ;?> // both are same.
```

What you are not getting here ?

Comment: undefinde variable `$username`

Comment: try checking the value of $user what you are receiving there ?

Comment: I tried to debug `$user` but it seems that it show nothnig